# Could not receive a response from promise to the console, using ES6 generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, es6-promise

Could not log the data to the Chrome browser console. Console just blank. I'm using http-server node package - works without errors (GET requests successful to script and jQuery files).

```
  window.onload = function(){
```

Generator function works without remarks.

```
  genWraper(function* generator() {
       var tweets = yield $.getJSON('/data/tweets.json');
       console.log(tweets);

       var friends = yield $.getJSON('/data/friends.json');
       console.log(friends);

       var videos = yield $.getJSON('/data/videos.json');
       console.log(videos);
  });


  function genWraper (generator){

    var myGen = generator();

  function handler(yielded) {
      if(!yielded.done){
         yielded.value.then(function(data){
          return handler(myGen.next(data));
         });
       }
   }
 return handler(myGen.next());
 };
}
```

Comment: what exists at those given paths? I would maybe add an error function to those `getJSON()` calls to see if there is a problem with parsing or retrieving.

Comment: Why are you even using generators? Just move forward to `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: Just saying: your `handler` doesn't `return` anything, and nowhere are you catching rejections from the promise or exceptions from the generator.